# Joining multiple tables by skipping On condition for few tables and join them alone

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to understand how we can `join` by skipping the `On` condition. Let me explain with example. If you notice in below query, there is no `ON` condition for `T3` and I am just joining with that table to `T4` table.

Question: How Data set will create and how that will combine to other other data set?

```
SELECT * FROM T1 
INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
INNER JOIN T3
LEFT JOIN T4 ON T3.ID = T4.ID
LEFT JOIN T5 ON T1.ID = T5.ID
```

Comment: @Gordon: it is valid syntax, with actual table this syntax is working for me in SQL Server. Why did you remove SQL Server TAG ?

Comment: @VijaySagar Because you also tagged `Oracle`, and those are two completely different DBMS products.  You didn't mention anywhere in your question that you were using `SQL Server`, so they both were removed until you could clarify.

Comment: @Siyual: Query is already written, i am trying to understand who this syntax works. How the standalone joining set will join to T1

Comment: @VijaySagar Different products behave differently.  Different behaviours lead to different answers.  In this case, I don't think it matters as much, but sagi's answer below should answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

Well, when there is no join relation, then you are basically performing a `CROSS JOIN` , your query is basically equivalent to :

```
SELECT * FROM T1 
INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
CROSS JOIN(SELECT * FROM T3
           LEFT JOIN T4 ON T3.ID = T4.ID)
LEFT JOIN T5 ON T1.ID = T5.ID
```

Comment: Oh ok, So each and every record will join to the standalone set. Is it right ?